# Can I change font charset on TRadioButton in Delphi 6 / Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, multilingual, charset

I have an old application build in Delphi 6. Working on customization where users can change the screen font and codepage. I do this by recursively going over all forms, containers, controls etc.

This works for the most part.

But strangely, I seem unable to change the font charset on TRadioButton. The group headline works fine, but the items inside do not inherit the container charset, although they DO inherit the font.

[image: Example showing groupbox and item, same content]

The sample text is entered in ANSI encoded chinese, charset GB2312.

I looked at the source of ExtCtrls, and tried something like

```
 TRadioButton(  thegroup.items[i] ).Font.Charset := programFilePrefFont.Charset;
```

.. but it gives med access violation.

I assume the result is different if Windows locale settings is changed globally, but that's hard on Win10.

I know I can work with TNT, but the change is involving a lot of places, so this is not for now. This has also become a little quest of curiousity.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: It's the same case in TpageControl and it's TTabSheet children, probably a few other parent/child relations as well.

Comment: Why not update your software to latest Delphi version? You have styling functions to make your GUI looks like you want. And no problem with character set and code page because character are now 16 bits (Unicode).

Comment: For this project it's not possible to update right now. Otherwise, I of course know that D10.4 offers all I want.  (In general, I get this comment every time I ask about D6 / D7, which is true but not really a useful response)

Answer (score 3):

To change the charset of a `TRadioButton` in a `TRadioGroup` use the `Buttons` property of the group, not the `Items` property.

E.g.

```
thegroup.Buttons[i].Font.Charset := programFilePrefFont.Charset;
```

Comment: Does that one exist in Delphi 6/7 ?

Comment: @HeartWare Yes, it does in D7, can't check with D6, but why would it not?

Comment: Because I've never encountered it when I needed to access the individual buttons of a RadioGroup (but that might just as well be me not being able to find it)

Comment: Unfortunately that property is not in D6. I tried to make a subclass of TcustomRadioGroup and make FButtons available, but no luck.

Comment: That's a pity, but you said "Delphi 6 / Delphi 7". So maybe you can upgrade the project to Delphi 7? Otherwise you may need to replace the `TRadioGroup`'s with separate `TGroupBox` and `TRadioButton`'s